Create a Hungarian index with xindy
The Hungarian alphabet is the following:

a, á, b, c, cs, d, dz, dzs, e, é, f, g, gy, h, i, í, j, k, l, ly, m,
n, ny, o, ó, ö, ő, p, q, r, s, sz, t, ty, u, ú, ü, ű, v, w, x, y, z,
zs

For the following MWE, however, I do not get a corresponding grouping:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-C utf8 -L hungarian]

\begin{document}

~
\index{cukor}
\index{csokor}
\index{gyomor}
\index{gumi}

\printindex

\end{document}

Here's the result:

This would be the expected result:

In my opinion it's a xindy's bug, but I see that the developer has been inactive since 2014, so I don't see the point of a bug report.
How could this problem be solved?

The source of the Hungarian alphabet definition file indeed seems a bit messy - it does provide separate groupings for G and Gy but they are both listed as G. This is different for C and Cs which also have separate groups but a different id - the source is ['C',  ['c','C']], ['Cs', ['cs','Cs','CS']] and ['G',  ['g','G']], ['G',  ['gy','Gy','GY']]. It doesn't look too difficult to modify and recompile the language definitions though, probably worth a try.

@Marijn - Thank you for your comment. This really seems to be the root of the problem. Unfortunately, I do not know how to recompile the language modules of the xindy source. Maybe it could be solved with a local xdy file?

Ha! So we Welsh are not the only ones who have letters which look like two :-).

i would drop xindy and try upmendex instead.

@Ulrike Fischer - Thanks for the tip, I'll try it.

It is possible to modify and recompile the language definition files. The following steps provide a quick-and-dirty approach. This bypasses the normal installation of Xindy with makefiles, so you need to make some additional changes to succesfully compile.

Download xindy-2.5.1.tar.gz from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing/xindy/base
Extract make_rules.pl from /xindy-2.5.1/make-rules/alphabets/ in that archive, and also extract utf8.pl.in from /xindy-2.5.1/make-rules/alphabets/hungarian/
Modify utf8.pl.in: change ['G',  ['gy','Gy','GY']] into ['Gy',  ['gy','Gy','GY']]
Make some further changes to avoid errors due to the quick-and-dirty approach:

change the line about the letter A into ['A',  ['a','A'],['á','Á'],['à','À']],
modify the last line in utf8.pl.in to do './make-rules.pl';, i.e., add ./


Modify make_rules.pl:

add $ARGV[0] = "utf8"; on top
remove or comment out the part about including test.xdy (around line 30, everything involving the $fn variable)


Now run perl utf8.pl.in
A new file utf8.xdy will be generated in the same folder
Locate the Hungarian version of utf8.xdy on your system. For me that is in /usr/share/xindy/lang/hungarian (Ubuntu, TeX Live installed with apt).
Replace the old file with the new one (make a backup of course)

Then the output of the MWE in your question will be as in your second screenshot.

@Marjin - Thanks for the detailed guide.

Instead of steps 8 and 9, you can put the regenerated utf8.xdy file in the same folder as the tex file. Then \makeindex[options=-C utf8 -L hungarian] in the tex file should be changed to \makeindex[options=-C utf8 -L hungarian -M utf8]. This works even on Overleaf.
